# List of tuples recursion, return updated version?

Tags: python, recursion, tuples

Is it possible to write a recursion function that passed list of tuples, key and value as arguments, then if the key exists -> set key and value, if not adds new key and value at the end of the list?

**Parameters have to be tuples,** I cannot change it to dictionary etc for requirements!

So far I came up with code looking like this, I know it's really messy:

```
def change(tupl, k, v):
    if len(tupl) == 0:
        return ((k, v),)
    if len(tupl) == 1:
        if k == tupl[0][0]:
            return ((k, v),)
        else:
            return (tupl[0],) + ((k, v),)
    elif k == tupl[0][0]:
        return ((k,v),) + change(tupl[1:], k, v)
    else:
        return (tupl[0],) + change(tupl[1:], k, v)
```

This list of tuples will be passed as argument:

```
tupl = (('n', 7), ('c', 1), ('k', 13), ('z', 9))
```

My two desired results would be:

```
print(change(tupl,'n', 111))

(('n', 111), ('c', 1), ('k', 13), ('z', 9))
```

And I know solution to deal with that, however my recursion also have to be able to do this:

```
print(change(tupl,'m', 1))

(('n', 7), ('c', 1), ('k', 13), ('z', 9), ('m', 1))
```

Problem is that if its

> print(change(tupl,'n', 111))

It will return list of tuples with unnecessary ('n', 111) at the end of the list.

Simply if the k and v exist in tupl, then return the list of tuple with the key and value updated. If k and v does not exist in passed tupl, then it always added at the end.

I can do either of these solutions,but cannot figure out the way to write a recursion that can do both.

Whats the best way to approach this? Any suggestion will be much appreciated!

Comment: Does the function have to be recursive?, Can there be more than one tupel with the key that needs its value changed - or can it stop when it finds  it?

Comment: Yes it have to be with recursion, and passed in key and value is always one!

Comment: `print(change(tuple,'n', 111))`  causes a `TypeError` did you mean `print(change(tupl,'n', 111))`?

Comment: Sorry it is tupl, edited!

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can remove some of the checks as they're either redundant or inferred:

```
def change(tupl, k, v):
    if len(tupl) == 0:  # or just `if not tupl:`
        return ((k, v),)
    if k == tupl[0][0]:
        return ((k, v),) + tupl[1:]
    return (tupl[0],) + change(tupl[1:], k, v)

>>> tupl = (('n', 7), ('c', 1), ('k', 13), ('z', 9))
>>> print(change(tupl,'n', 111))
(('n', 111), ('c', 1), ('k', 13), ('z', 9))
>>> print(change(tupl,'m', 1))
(('n', 7), ('c', 1), ('k', 13), ('z', 9), ('m', 1))
```